# How to get the ListItem based on the column name in ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, selectcommand

I have a drop down list box like following. Under some condition, in the databound event I want to remove the items whose bitActive is set to 0 (inactive). I did not put a WHERE bitAcive!=0 in the selectCommand, because I only want to remove them under some conditions. Is there any way I could iterate the items and check the value of bitActive?

```
<tr>
            <td width="30%" align="right">Location<span class="littlefont">*</span></td>
            <td width="70%" align="left">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLocation" runat="server" 
                    DataSourceID="SqlDSLocation" DataTextField="txtRefLocation_Name" 
                    DataValueField="intRefLocation_ID" ondatabound="ddlLocation_DataBound">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDSLocation" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SPRConnectionString %>" 
                    SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [intRefLocation_ID], [txtRefLocation_Name], [location], [bitActive] FROM [tblRefLocation] ORDER BY [intRefLocation_ID]">
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In codebehind you can call the [`SQLDataSource.Select()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.select.aspx) method:

```
System.Data.DataView dv = (System.Data.DataView)SqlDSLocation.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
```

And then iterate through the rows returned, finding the "bitActive" rows who are set to zero and removing them from your `DropDownList` (code sort of hacked from the example linked above):

```
foreach(System.Data.DataRow row in dv.Table.Rows)
{
    // This is approximate logic, tailor this to fit your actual data
    if (row["bitActive"].ToString() == "False")
    {
        ddlLocation.Items.Remove(row["intRefLocation_ID"].ToString());
    }
}
```

Note that this is not removing these rows from your SQL table.  Make sure you don't databind your `DropDownList` again after this - otherwise all the stuff you just removed will return.

**EDIT:** For a more efficient and elegant solution, see [James Johnson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9980478/).

Comment: Not to criticize the poster's answer, but this is neither an efficient or elegant way to solve the problem...

Comment: @JamesJohnson No, that doesn't sound like criticism *at all* =)  +1 to your answer, it *is* very elegant!

Comment: I really wasn't criticizing you, because you stuck with the implementation OP was already using. I was just pointing out that there were more efficient ways. I hope you didn't take it as a slight on you, because I've seen you post some solid code.

Comment: @JamesJohnson I appreciate the compliment! Sorry I guess I did take your comment a bit personally, but it makes more sense now.  That'll teach me to make assumptions =)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing items in the `ItemDataBound` event, why not just filter the datasource before binding it?:

```
var table = new DataTable("MyTable"); //assume it's populated
if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    var results = table.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.bitActive).AsDataView().ToTable();
    if (!results.HasErrors)
    {
        DropDownList1.DataSource = results;
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
    }        
}
```